# React Native build fails in Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native

React Native build fails in Xcode.

Error message:
 `Build input file cannot be found: '/....../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/vo.app/vo'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?`

try to Clean build folder and DerivedData folder. nothing helps.